# How to use std::enable_if to conditionally select a variadic constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, enable-if

I am trying to make a class which should inherit the constructors from other classes but without inheriting from those classes itself.

At one point during the initialization of my class, I want to use perfect forwarding to create an object of the type whose constructor matched the given arguments.

Except for the default constructor with no arguments, there shall be no ambiguities.

This is my code:

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//NOTE: this class is just an example to demonstrate the problem
class String {
    public:
        //default constructor to prevent ambiguity
        String() {}

        //construct from wstring
        template<typename... Args>
        String(enable_if<is_constructible<wstring, Args...>::value, Args>::type&&... args) : ws(forward<Args>(args)...) {}

        //construct from string
        template<typename... Args>
        String(enable_if<is_constructible<string, Args...>::value, Args>::type&&... args) : s(forward<Args>(args)...) {}
    private:
        string s;
        wstring ws;
};

void foo(const String& string) {
}

int main()
{
    foo(L"123");
    foo("123");
    return 0;
}
```

I tried many things but I just can't get it to work.

- In the current approach `enable_if` fails to automatically deduct the template args (I think)
- Since I use the constructor I can't use `enable_if` on the return value
- Adding another default parameter for `enable_if` won't work because the constructor is variadic
- When I remove `enable_if` from the function arguments the compiler complains about invalid overloads (of course)

Is there an elegant way to solve this problem?

*Edit:*
The one implicit conversion that is allowed by the standard should not occur in my class. *[example code edited]*

One solution that works with the example above would be to define a single variadic constructor and perfect forward the arguments to a conditioned initialization function. However, I would like to avoid this overhead because members need to be default constructed and this may not work in other cases.

(Feel free to edit the question if things can be made clearer)

Comment: Good question and I don't have an answer. FWIW, *without* variadic templates it [works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c799960a369ccf7e) by using defaulted parameters.

Comment: I asked near related question also in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18700072/using-sfinae-to-select-different-method-implementations-in-a-clase-template. One answer was also to use specialization instead :-)

Comment: As I said in a comment to Klaus' solution: Only **one** user-defined conversion is performed implicitly. Either from the string literal to `std::basic_string` or from a `std::basic_string` to your `String` type, but not both.

Answer (score 2):

I can't understand the problem and also the solution. If I want to use 2 different types for a method or a constructor I can simply write both types. There is no need to have a template with SFINAE for that reason! This can simply done by specialization.

```
class A 
{
    public:
    template <typename ... Args>
    A(const wstring &, Args ... );

    template <typename ... Args>
    A(const string &, Args ...);
};
```

To have a template which exact match for only one type is not really semantically a template :-)

After reading your comment I got this solution:

```
class foo
{
    public:
        template <typename ... Args>
        foo( const string &&x, Args ... ) { cout << "Using string" << endl; }

        template <typename ... Args>
        foo( const wstring &&x, Args ...) { cout << "Using wstring" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    foo("123");
    foo(L"123");

    foo("123", 1);
    foo(L"123", 1.11);
    return 0;
}
```

and this return as expected:

```
Using string
Using wstring
Using string
Using wstring
```

Comment: True. This actually works in my current case and not noticing that is a little embarrassing. The only problem is that it may use one implicit conversion which I guess was trying to avoid.

Comment: An implicit conversion should only take place if the parameter did not match exactly. As I understand your example you have 2 explicit defined types. And in addition, if you could specify your types with a enable_if you have a different effect: If your given type did not match exactly you will have no instantiations of any of the templates which results in an compile error.

Comment: There's an implicit conversion from the supplied string literals to the parameter type (either `wstring` or `string`). By the way, this is an example where a by-value sink argument (instead of by-const-ref) is more performant, if you don't provide rvalue-ref overloads additionally.

Comment: You are absolutely right! The given types should match exactly but did not in my given example. BTW: It should also be possible to catch rvalue reference types.

Comment: Actually after checking, it does not work in my real case which is a little bit different from the given example. I should think more before writing. What I ultimately trying to achieve is to have a void foo(const String& string); function that i can call like foo("123"); and foo(L"123); instead of foo(string("123")) and foo(wstring(L"123"); Basically, this is synthetic sugar for a framework i am writing.

Comment: @user1492625 That sounds like a sequence of two user-defined conversions? Only one of them is performed implicitly.

Comment: It would be nice to add your real code as addition to your question. This simplifies reading for further readers of this thread and give us a chance to reproduce your code in our own workspace.